# condition logic on a RenderSection

Tags: razor

In one of my templates, I have this:

```
<aside class="headline image right">            
    @RenderSection("HeaderImage", required: false)              
</aside>
```

In the corresponding pages, I use this to populate the image:

```
@section HeaderImage { <img src="whatever.jpg" alt="" /> }
```

Is there some simple conditional logic I can wrap around that whole containing 'aside' to stop it outputting the code if HeaderImage is left empty / not provided in the page template? Just looking for something as straight forward and simple as possible as I don't want to include the aside code anywhere where someone updating files could randomly delete / edit it etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `IsSectionDefined` method:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("HeaderImage"))
{
    <aside class="headline image right">            
        @RenderSection("HeaderImage")
    </aside>
}
```

I've now removed the `required: false` parameter as we are calling the `RenderSection` method only if it has been defined. You could also have an `else` condition to specify some default markup if the section has not been defined in the view.

Comment: Works a treat, thank you! :) Shall make a note of that one in future!